# 'Exceptions.NameError' > "Name 'sheet_count' is not defined" Error in Python Code

Tags: python

I know this is something simple but for some reason I am having trouble remembering. In my code I am getting a name is not define for sheet_count. This means I would have to define at top correct. For Example: Is it sheet_count = true? My code is below:

```
import arcpy, os, sys, string
from os import path as p
from arcpy import mapping as m

#Make parameters for people to choose mxd and folder of PDFs to compare

mxdList = string.split(arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0), ";")
pdf_path = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)

#Use Search Cursor to go through Attribuite Table to get Sheet number info

for mapDoc in mxdList:
    arcpy.AddMessage(mapDoc)
    mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(mapDoc)
    for lyr in m.ListLayers(mxd, "*, Grid"):
        if lyr.description == "*, Grid":
            max_list = []
            rows = arcpy.SearchCursor(lyr)
            for row in rows:
                max_list.append(row.Sheet_ID)
            sheet_count = max(max_list)
            arcpy.AddMessage('Sheet count: %s'%sheet_count)
            print 'Sheet count: %s'%sheet_count
        else:
            arcpy.AddError('No Layers in %s match data source'%mapDoc)
```

Answer (score 2):

So what I cannot tell because you did not format your python code is how the variable "sheet_count" is scoped.

If your code looks like this:

```
for row in rows:
    max_list.append(row.Sheet_ID)
    sheet_count = max(max_list)
    arcpy.AddMessage('Sheet count: %s'%sheet_count)
print 'Sheet count: %s'%sheet_count
```

Then you have scoping issue as "sheet_count" does not exist outside of the for loop.  So you should define "sheet_count" outside of the for statement like so:

```
sheet_count = 0
for row in rows:
    max_list.append(row.Sheet_ID)
    sheet_count = max(max_list)
    arcpy.AddMessage('Sheet count: %s'%sheet_count)
 print 'Sheet count: %s'%sheet_count
```

Comment: Thank You so much! That what it was. Where would I have gotten that information? (i.e. learn that) And how do I format Python code for these questions so I can do it right next time?

Comment: It just takes time to if you are just starting.  You need to indent 4 spaces.   This site uses markdown for text formatting:  http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help